# Some very odd behaviour of \verb and \verbatim in connection with TeXMaker

Tags: texmaker, verbatim

I cannot but assume that whatever `<text>` is placed between the delimiters (in this case `+`) in `\verb+<text>+` and `\verbatim+<text>+` has no effect whatsoever on the world outside the delimiters. The following MWE seems to tell us  otherwise. `\verb` appears to effect the `structure panel` of `TeXMaker` suggesting this might be a `TeXMaker`-only problem (using Version 5.0.2), but `\verbatim` messes up the `.pdf` output as well as the `structure panel`, so I am completely puzzled.

```
\documentclass{book}
% RN. 11 Nov 2018
%=======================
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\section*{Preface}
"We wish to show that \verb+\part{name}\label{name}+ sets a label etc." promptly 
introduces Part name in the structure section of the TeXMaker screen, however, no ill 
effects in the .pdf output are observed. 
\chapter{A}
\section{A1}\label{A1}
\subsection{A11}
The same effect is observed in the structure section of TeXMaker when using verbatim 
in place of verb, i.e. \verbatim+\subsection{subname}\label{subname}+, except from this 
point forward the .pdf output is screwed up as well.  
\subsection{A12}
\chapter{B}
\section{B1}
\section{B2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\verbatim` ever supposed to appear in a document?

Comment: `\verbatim` is a syntax error, it is not surprising that syntax highlighters and editors do not pick up on all verbatim uses, yo see the same  with syntax highlighting on this site, it is not possible without running a full tex execution to parse all instances of verbatim text correctly

Comment: the "warning" from tex `(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 14 (\begingroup)
### bottom level` should be treated as an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `\verbatim+x+` doesn't throw an error when the `verbatim` package is loaded is a by-product of how the `verbatim` environment is redefined.

If you don't load it, you get a much worse error, namely

```
Runaway argument?
+x+^^M\end{document}^^M
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

followed by the input prompt, but you can only “pull the power chord” if you want to exit. With a front end using `-interaction=nonstopmode` you get instead

```
! Emergency stop.
```

It is ***always*** an error to use `\xyz` mid document when `xyz` is an environment. (The converse, that is using `\begin{macro}` and `\end{macro}`, is allowed when `\macro` has been defined with `\newcommand`).

For instance `\flushleft` mid document doesn't give an error, but messes up the output. The correct document level command is `\raggedright`.

The “macro forms” for an environment, that is `\xyz` and `\endxyz` after `\newenvironment{xyz}{...}{...}` can (mostly) be used in the definition of other environments, but they should always appear in the start and end part of the new environment's definition respectively. Beware that some environments *do not* allow this.

The `verbatim` package indeed recommends using `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim` for defining new verbatim-based environments. But `\verbatim+x+` is definitely wrong.

About the structure laid out by TeXStudio: it cannot discriminate among `\label` or sectional commands appearing inside `\verb` or a `verbatim` environment. That's the way it is.

Comment: In summary then, this was a case of making naive assumptions about the functionality of `\verb+...+`. And `\verbatim` needs to be used like an environment, i.e. `\verbatim` … `\endverbatim`, using the syntax `\verbatim+...+` causes havoc.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth `\verbatim+...+` does not do anything sensible except messing up the output. Moreover, `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim` should only be used for defining new environments, not in the document body, as I wrote in my answer.